# Rails 4: How to merge loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, merge

I was wondering on how to merge loops within rails.

Do I need to do that in the Controller, or is that even possible in a view?
If I wonder how to decide which partial to render.

For instance I have to models: `item` and `receipe`.

First, how do I merge all recipes and items into one loop?
Second, if I want to render for each `receipe` the partial `_receipe` and for each `item` the partial `_item`, how am I supposed to da that?

Thanks in advance for each help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work out of the box:

```
# in the controller
items    = Item.all         # some scope on Items
receipes = Receipe.all      # some scope on Receipes
@things = items + receipes  # combine them into one variable

# in the view
render @things              # renders a collection and renders for each item in 
                            # the array a partial named like the item's class name
```